# CSS - Part of text vertically aligned to bottom of table cell

Tags: css, html-table, vertical-alignment

**How can I align one sentence at the top of the `td` and another sentence at the bottom?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add another div with

```
.bottom-div {
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;        
}
```

and the wrapper div (or table-cell) just need `position: relative;`

http://jsfiddle.net/RnZPM/

The other way is to build a table in this cell with height: 100% and to rows with align: top and bottom.

Comment: Perfect, thanks for the quick response and the fiddle - helped a lot

Comment: works only with fixed height of table-cell element though

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this without using some further markup within the `td` itself. One way of achieving this would be by using absolute positioning:

```
<table style="height:200px">
    <tr>
        <td style="position:relative;">
            <div style="position: absolute; top:0px;">Top</div>
            <div style="position: absolute; bottom:0px;">Bottom</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I've put the styling inline to show you exactly what is being applied where. See [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/GjDjQ/1/) for a stylesheet-based equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

simple......!

```
        <style type="text/css">
        td { height:50px;}
        </style>

        <table width="50%" border="1">
          <tr>
            <td style="vertical-align:bottom">abc</td>
             <td style="vertical-align:top">xyz</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
```